# Update a column with comma separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to update a single column within my table with multiple values.

```
Update Table_cust
Set Cust_Value=('1','2','3')
where cust_id in ('ABC','XYZ')
```

When I run this I get an error saying right parenthesis missing, now this is because it is expecting me to update one value at a time which I can't.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, what is your desired result? Which rows would get which value?

Comment: Please store only 1 value in a table cell. It is very bad DB design to  store multiple values.

Comment: Rather than fighting the symptom you should fix the problem and re-design your data model. Stop storing comma separated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Update Table_cust
Set Cust_Value='1,2,3'
where cust_id in ('ABC','XYZ')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Update Table_cust
Set Cust_Value='1,2,3'
where cust_id in ('ABC','XYZ')
```